# Tabs by hand with addClass and removeClass

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to write, what I thought was, a simple jQuery function to switch the look of a selected vs. not-selected tab.  Here is what I have:

CSS:

```
ul#menu li a
{ font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 28px 5px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #635B53 url(../images/tab.png) no-repeat 100% 0;}

ul#menu li.selected 
{ margin: 2px 2px 0 0;
  background: #635B53 url(../images/tab_selected.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="menuHome"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li id="menuNews"><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
  <li id="menuDownloads"><a href="downloads.html">Downloads</a></li>
  <li id="menuFeedback"><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
  <li id="menuContact"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menu li a').live ( 'click', function()
{
    $(this).parent().find('a.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

What happens is this: I click one of the tabs, the tab changes to the lighter color as it should, then it switches back to the original dark gray.  I've run it in FireBug and it clearly shows that the jQuery function changes the tab to the light color, but when I "continue", and the program goes back into the jQuery library, it switched it back to the original!

I have tried everything I can think of... a little help?!?

**UPDATE**

Even if we do not worry about removing the selected class from the wrapped set and simply concentrate on adding the class, the JQ code still performs the same. In other words, this:

```
$('#menu li a').live ( 'click', function()
{
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

"Flashes" the light color - it displays the lighter color then immediately returns to the darker color. Yikes! Someone is changing it back... who?

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/hGbCd/

Comment: Tim, thanks! I was unaware of jsfiddle.net and I think it is a great resource. The code you show there does exactly what all of the below does: it changes to the light color, then changes back.

Comment: Tim, BTW, it worked at jsfiddle but not in my local code. This tells me something else "up the chain" is changing it back.

Comment: Timothy, Tim's jsfiddle seems to work perfectly for me, in Chrome v18 on Mac… what browser are you targeting? - edit: just saw your response, nvm about browser compat

Comment: @TimothyKnautz - there *are* some subtle differences in the fiddle that I posted. That's probably why it's not working locally for you.

Comment: Lübnah, should probably let everyone know my specifics: Ubuntu 10.04 64bit with Firefox 11.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#menu li a').live ('click', function()
{
    $("a",$(this).parents("ul")).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});​
```

Comment: tpaksu, thanks for your reply! Your code does exactly what mine does. The tab goes light-colored for a quick moment, then goes back to the original dark color. Id there possibly a bubbling issue here?!?

Comment: do you have any click event on "li"?

Comment: No.  Only the live click event handler for $('#menu li a')

Comment: And you may use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()` if there's another "ul" element wrapping around the "ul".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your jQuery code.  Your first line uses `.parent()` which will just go up to the `li` element of the `a` element that was clicked.  The `.find()` call then searches that `li`... it does NOT search any of the adjacent `li` elements which is what you're intending.

What you want to do instead is use `$(this).closest('ul').find('a.selected').removeClass('selected')`.  The next line you want to add the "selected" class to the `a` element, so you'd want `$(this).addClass('selected')` instead (notice you don't need/want to use `.parent()` here).

Comment: You could combine both lines in to this: `$(this).closest('ul').find('a.selected').removeClass('selected').end().addClass('selected')`

Comment: Eli, thanks for your reply! Your explanation was great, thanks! I could not get your code to work, though. See above, do you think there might be a bubbling issue?

Comment: I created a fiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/w3SHC/

I copied your code exactly (killed the links) and noticed what your problem was - it was your CSS.  You had the background for all `a` elements set to one image, then had the background for all selected `li` elements set to another.  The problem was that the background for your `a` elements was sitting atop the `li`... regardless of its state, so you never really saw the background change (probably why the flicker and that's it).  I tweaked your CSS ever so slightly (I narrowed `.selected` down to an `a` element).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#menu li > a").click(function() {
    parentLi = $(this).closest("li");
    parentLi.hasClass("selected")?(
        parentLi.removeClass("selected")
    ):(
        parentLi.addClass("selected"),
        parentLi.siblings().removeClass("selected")
    )
});
```

Comment: Phil, thanks for your reply! Your code does exactly what mine does and tpaksu's above too. The tab goes light-colored for a quick moment, then goes back to the original dark color. Id there possibly a bubbling issue here?!?

Comment: My code removes the "selected" class when clicking on a link already with the "selected" class, which you might not need. I can't reproduce the problem you're having though, with all the browsers I've tested: Firefox 11, Chrome 18, IE6.